# TypeError: parsed is undefined on angularjs service unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-service

I am trying to make a unit test for a service that uses $http. I am using Jasmine and I keep on getting this error:

> TypeError: parsed is undefined in angular.js (line 13737)

This is what my service looks like:

```
angular.module('myapp.services', [])
.factory('inviteService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http) {
    var inviteService = {
        token: '',

        getInvite: function(callback, errorCallback) {
            $http.get('/invites/' + this.token + '/get-invite')

            .success(function(data) {
                callback(data);
            })

            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                errorCallback(status);
            });
        }
    };

    return inviteService;
}]);
```

This is what my test looks like:

```
describe ('Invite Service', function () {
  var $httpBackend, inviteService, authRequestHandler;

  var token = '1123581321';

  beforeEach(module('myapp.services'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('/invites/' + token + '/get-invite').respond({userId: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});
    inviteService = $injector.get('inviteService');
  }));

  afterEach (function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation ();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest ();
  });

  describe ('getInvite', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      inviteService.token = token;
    });

    it ('should return the invite', function () {
      $httpBackend.expectGET('/invites/' + token + '/get-invite');
      inviteService.getInvite();
      $httpBackend.flush();
    });
  });
});
```

I am pretty new to unit testing angularjs based apps and I used the example in the angularjs documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

I am not sure what I could be missing, and I already tried different things and I always get the same error, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/58aLjyp9/1/ and it works perfectly fine. Maybe the problem is not on the test itself. Can I ask what is your angularjs version ?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay, I'm still having the problem but I can see that you got it working on the fiddle, I am using v1.2.11 of angular. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I have updated the fiddle with your angulr version but it still be ok. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/58aLjyp9/2/. One thing to notice on this line "$httpBackend.expectGET('/invites/' + token + '/get-invite');" you forgot to call respond as I do on my fiddle. Except that everything is ok, you can take a look through your code where you call variables parsed or maybe it relates to $parse service in Angularjs

Answer (score 7):

The `parsed` variable is the URL from the service in question. It is `undefined` for one of the following reasons:

- URL is malformed
- $http.get is not called
- `token` is not defined
- `sucess` and `error` callbacks have no `data`
- `.respond` is not called
- `.respond` does not include a response object as an argument

For example:

```
 describe('simple test', test);

 function test()
   {
   it('should call inviteService and pass mock data', foo);

   function foo() 
     {
     module('myapp.services');
     inject(myServiceTest);

     function myServiceTest(inviteService, $httpBackend)
       {
       $httpBackend.expect('GET', /.*/).respond(200, 'bar');

       function callback(){};

       inviteService.getInvite.token = '1123581321';
       inviteService.getInvite(callback, callback);

       $httpBackend.flush();

       expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
       }
     }
   }
```

**References**

- [AngularJS source: angular-mocksSpec.js - "should throw exception when only parsed body differs from expected body object"](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ngMock/angular-mocksSpec.js)
- [AngularJS source: urlUtils.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/urlUtils.js)
- [AngularJS source: urlUtilsSpec.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/urlUtilsSpec.js)